# How to run angular2 and spring mvc based rest api on the same tomcat server?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, angular

I am building an angular 2 app that has to use spring mvc based rest api at the backend. I am using maven, not using spring-boot, and want to map the index.html of angular2 to the base URL of the deployed WAR file. I am seeing the index.html to be present in the MyApplication named folder in webapps folder of tomcat, but somehow trying to access the site via the base URL gives no resource available. Could somebody help me. This is my layout.

web.xml

```
<display-name>MyApplication</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rochak.*" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/angular/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.html</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

MyController.java in com/rochak/controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value="*")
public String getIndex(ModelMap model){
    return "index";
}
}
```

and angular folder lies in WEB-INF folder with it's index.html

Why is index.html not being found by spring mvc?

Comment: add a <welcome-file-list> in your web.xml

Comment: Your request mapping should be "/**" or just "/" for the homepage. You should also return the directory that yor index.html file is in and it should be index.html not just index. 

EX: @RequestMapping("/")
   public String appHome() {
       return "/build/index.html";
}

Comment: Hi Rochak, Can you post angular directory structure under WEB-INF, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'url-pattern' to something like '/server/'. It would work.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it myself by setting <base href='./'>